# Cleanest way to write a sort method in JavaScript that sorts on multiple object properties

Tags: javascript, sorting

This is a sort of code golf / code cleanliness and conciseness question. I have an object I want to sort in JavaScript, and I'm wondering what the shortest and cleanest way to do this.

Given objest like this:

```js
items = [
 {name: "Pierre",  boosted: true,  rank: 1   },
 {name: "Burhan",  boosted: false, rank: null},
 {name: "Ellise",  boosted: false, rank: 1   },
 {name: "Glenn",   boosted: true,  rank: 2   },
 {name: "Zidane",  boosted: false, rank: null},
 {name: "Antonia", boosted: false, rank: 2   },
];
```

I need to sort with these requirements:

1. Boosted items first, then by `name` ascending within multiple boosted items.
2. Next put `rank`, ascending, where rank != null. Doesn't matter how we sort if there's a tie in `rank`.
3. When rank = null, sort by `name` ascending.

So essentially three buckets to sort the items by, then within each bucket sort by name. Rank isn't normalized, it can be any valid number.

The resulting list above sorted should look like this:

```js
sorted = [
 {name: "Glenn",   boosted: true,  rank: 2   },
 {name: "Pierre",  boosted: true,  rank: 1   },
 {name: "Ellise",  boosted: false, rank: 1   },
 {name: "Antonia", boosted: false, rank: 2   },
 {name: "Burhan",  boosted: false, rank: null},
 {name: "Zidane",  boosted: false, rank: null},
];
```

I wrote this long method:

```js
items.sort((a, b) => {
    // Boosted
    if (a.boosted && b.boosted) {
        return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
    } else if (a.boosted && !b.boosted) {
        return -1;
    } else if (!a.boosted && b.boosted) {
        return 1;
    }

    // Ranked
    if (a.rank != null && b.rank != null) {
        return a - b;
    } else if (a.rank != null && b.rank == null) {
        return -1;
    } else if (a.rank == null && b.rank != null) {
        return 1;
    }

    // Default by name
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
});
```

It works, but I think there are much better ways to do this, and I'm curious what styles other people recommend. What's the shortest solution I could write? What's the cleanest? What's the fastest? (Since the sort method could get called many times during a sort operation)

Comment: What you could do is extract it into a function... items.sort(compareByIsBoostedAndRank)

Comment: Can `rank` be negative or `0`?

Comment: Yes, `rank` can be negative or positive (I know it makes things a bit more complicated).

Comment: In spreadsheets, I sometimes "cheat" for this kind of sorting...  Figure out the max number of characters for name/check the data for it, figure out the max number of digits for rand/check, add a property for each object, say "sortKey" and set it's value to concatenation of "B" for boosted/"X" for not + `(name+(" ").repeat(max chars)).slice(0,max chars)` + `(" ".repeat(max digits)+rank).slice(-max digits)` and then sort by that.  * edited `0` to ` ` because of `-` asciis...

Comment: or, sort by rank, then by name, then by boosted: `array.sort(byRank).sort(byName).sort(byBoosted)` where byXxxx is a compare function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-` on booleans and numbers. You can use `||` to chain multiple sort criteria, short-circuiting when the first doesn't return `0`.

In your case that might be

```
items.sort((a, b) =>
  b.boosted - a.boosted ||
  (a.rank == null) - (b.rank == null) ||
  a.rank - b.rank ||
  a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
);
```

if you were just to sort by differently priotised columns. However, you've got the special requirement that boosted items should be sorted differently than non-boosted items, so you indeed need a conditional statement thrown in:

```
items.sort((a, b) =>
  b.boosted - a.boosted ||
  (a.boosted
    ? a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
    : (a.rank == null) - (b.rank == null) ||
      (a.rank != null
        ? a.rank - b.rank
        : a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
      )
  )
);
```

Comment: You may want to check the output again. It doesn't match

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Oh, right, rank should be ascending not descending. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I do this way:

```js
const items = [
 {name: "Pierre",  boosted: true,  rank: 1   },
 {name: "Burhan",  boosted: false, rank: null},
 {name: "Ellise",  boosted: false, rank: 1   },
 {name: "Glenn",   boosted: true,  rank: 2   },
 {name: "Zidane",  boosted: false, rank: null},
 {name: "Antonia", boosted: false, rank: 2   },
];

const gKey=({name,boosted,rank})=>`${boosted?0:1}_${(rank!=null)?('000'+rank).slice(-3):'999'}_${name}` 

items.sort((a,b)=>gKey(a).localeCompare(gKey(b)) )

// proof:
items.forEach(e=>console.log(JSON.stringify(e),'  (key->',gKey(e),')'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```